# Mysql restore all data from Master

Tags: mysql, replication

MySQl Slave replication server got crashed and I am missing around 60 tables, some table structure and data which present in master and by DB size is more than 25Gb, How I Can restore to resolve issue. 
Please help to solve it ASAP.
Thanking you in advance... 
Nikhil

Comment: That is NOT the kind of questions we answer here, see http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score -1):

You need to restore the data from master.

1. Take a dump of missing tables from master using

   `mysqldump  --singl-transaction>missing_tables.sql`
2. Stop the slave.
3. Restore the dump file in slave using

   `mysql -uroot -p<missing_tables.sql`
4. Start the replication slave will catchup.